# Is there a way to convert a string to an array? React js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, javascript-objects

Hello to all the community ... I am new to using sql server and as I understand it I cannot save array data in the database with which I am using the varchar data type and I have a problem ... The API returns the following in string type:

```js
`[{title: frontpartID, state: false},{title: backpartID, state: true}]`
```

And I'm needing to convert it to object type ... something like that:

```
[
 { title: "frontpartID", state: false },
 { title: "backpartID", state: true },
]
```

so we can go through it with the .filter function:

```
object.filter((x) => x.state === true)
```

I would really appreciate any help as I am new to this field ... Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If it was formatted as JSON you could pass it into `JSON.parse`. Otherwise you're likely going to need to manually parse it.

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver I don't think so since most answers seem to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: The duplicates are all parsing JSON strings... there must be another which parses non-JSON strings?